# Using variable twice without cloning in rust

Tags: rust

I am wondering why this code gives an error :

```rust
for file in dir {
    println!("Name {:?}", &file.unwrap().path().display());
    println!("Type {:?}", &file.unwrap().file_type().unwrap());
}
```

but this code does not

```rust
for file in dir {
     let a = file.unwrap();
     println!("{:?}", a.path());
     println!("{:?}", a.file_type());
}
```

From what I understand, the first example has `file` moved to `println`, but why does that not happen for the second method? Why does using a reference in the first method still cause the data to be moved or is it the method being called on `file` that is causing the problem?

Working example in [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5b5977bc73d4b1b90062cdaa5491b07e)

Comment: "*or is it the method being called on `file` that is causing the problem?*"—bingo. `Result::unwrap` takes ownership of `self`.  You can first call `Result::as_ref` if you only want a borrow: e.g. `file.as_ref().unwrap()...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line is to be [read like this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence) (notice parentheses):

```
println!("Name {:?}", &(((file.unwrap()).path()).display()));
```

So, the first call [`file.unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) consumes (i.e. moves) `file`, and after this, `path` and `display` are computed. `file` can not be used after this move.

In the second example you store the result of `file.unwrap` into a temporary (`a`). Since [`path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.path) does *not* move its argument, `a` can still be used after the first usage.